# CSS two column layout with constant sidebar width

Tags: html, css

How do I define a design using `div`s (or html5 `section`)

> | content - fill the area |    < gap 20px >  |sidebar width 200px sticks to
>   the right |

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Write like this:

```
div{
    height:80px;
    background:red;
}
.fixed{
    float:right;
    margin-left:20px;
    width:200px;
}
.dynamic{
    background:green;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

Check this http://jsfiddle.net/gtmXE/

Comment: How to make the content `DIV` fill the entire width when the sidebar is not present?

Comment: Check my fiddle & remove the fixed div from HTML.Then you will get what you want

Answer (score 3):

```
<div id="sidebar" style="float:right; width:200px;">
<div id="content" style="margin-right:220px">
    main content
</div>
```

Comment: How to make the content `DIV` fill the entire width when the sidebar is not present?

Comment: you better make two site templates, one with sidebar, the other without. But if u insists, you may resorts to javascript. such as  if( $('#sidebar') == undefined ){ $('#content').css('width', 100%);}